# Using *not* in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, verb-forms

I really wonder, which specific structure should be suitable according to the table below for the following sentence:

> The table shows that navigation **is included or not included** in related cars.

Or

> The table shows that navigation **is included or not** in related cars.

The table:

```
         Navigation
| BMW  |    1
| Opel |    -
```

I want to use **not** because Opel has no any navigation feature.

Comment: Usually *navigation* is a non-count noun.

Comment: I might rephrase it as: *The table shows whether navigation is included in related cars or not.* -- Pushing *not* to the end would emphasize the word "not". (Also consider *a navigator* or *a navigation system* as alternatives to *navigation*.)

Comment: One could also say "whether or not navigation is included in related cars", which as Damkerng says would de-emphasize the word not in relation to navigation and related cars.  I would put the "not" either there or at the end.  In any case, "whether" is better than "that" here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table shows **whether** navigation **is included or not** in related cars.

Comment: 'that' doesn't go with 'or' as Stoney B pointed out to one of of my answers.

Comment: In conversational English you'll also frequently hear it phrase as "The table shows **whether or not** navigation is included in related cars".

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for one sentence and there could be many options to convey the message.

For instance, I may prefer telling...

> *The table shows whether the car has (built-in) navigation (system).*

Please note that *whether* will take care of the option of not having navigation. We often say...

> *I went out to check whether it was raining.*

Comment: Personally, I'd almost always say "I went out to check **if** it was raining."

Comment: I heard the sound and went out to check whether it's raining. What's the problem in this? No condition here just options it rains or doesn't.

Comment: Oh, it's just in that particular example, *whether* sounded too heavy / formal for me to use.  Concerns like formality aside, *whether* and *if* are interchangeable in that grammatical situation (as markers of subordinate interrogative clauses), and you can use whichever you prefer.  But there is one problem, since you ask: ***it's*** is a contraction of ***it is*** or ***it has***, but not ***it was***.  So in your latest example, I'd say instead "I heard the sound and went out to check whether **it was** raining."

Answer (score 0):

A common way to express this concept is

> The table shows that navigation *may or may not be included* in related cars.